# EF Core Tools not working on dotnet core 3 preview 4

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, command-line-interface

I am trying to develop some web APIs using dotnet core 3 preview 4. I am familiar to dotnet core and its libraries like EF core and Identity and etc. But now with the version 3 preview 4, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools does not work and the command `dotnet ef migrations add ...` tells this message:

> Cannot find command 'dotnet ef', please run the following command to
>   install
>
> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

the csproj file is like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0-preview4-19216-03" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview4.19216.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview4.19216.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview4.19216.3"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and also I have tried `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef` but not solved my issue. As the version 3 preview 4 is newly announced, I can't find any documentation about this on official or third-part sites.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Edit:**

At this point dotnet core 3 is no longer preview, so select our version accordingly. ([Check version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef))

---

First make sure that,

1. You're using the .NET Core SDK 3.0 Preview, type `dotnet --info` and see there's a line like,

> ```
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>   3.0.100-preview4-011223 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> ```

2. You ran `dotnet restore` on the project
3. You are `cd`ed to the project's (*.csproj) directory

With Entity Framework Core 3.0 Preview 4, dotnet-ef tool is no longer part of the .NET Core SDK. Uninstall the stable version of `dotnet-ef` tool (2.2.4 at this point) using,

```
dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef
```

Then install the preview or latest stable, ([Check version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef))

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview4.19216.3
```

After that `dotnet ef` should work fine.

Answer (score 13):

.NET Core 3.0 introduces [Local Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#local-tools):

> Local tools are similar to global tools but are associated with a particular location on disk. Local tools aren't available globally and are distributed as NuGet packages.

dotnet Core and, also, EF Core, are evolving fast. It's easy to have several projects/solutions at different dotnet versions. With Local Tools you can configure specific version tools by project.

**Steps to configure tool by project:**

```
dotnet new tool-manifest  
#executing this at sln level (or with your projecte) a new .config file is created

#check lasts versions at:
#https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ef/

dotnet tool install --local dotnet-ef --version 3.1.4
#this will configure dotnet ef tool

dotnet ef
#should run at this point
```

At this point your ef migrations/database command must runs.

When people clone your repo should run:

```
dotnet tool restore
```

Comment: shouldn't the last line be `dotnet dotnet-ef`? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: skip the --version param in the 2nd command to use the latest version

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-preview4.19216.3
```